# How to get value's of ( Enter ,Space,Clear button's in virtual keyboard) with Text Watcher

Tags: android

I am trying to get values of space ,enter ,clear buttons but not success
i am trying to display a toast message also ,when i press enter ,space ,clear(one of them)
it should give me a message that "Enter pressed ".
and it should happened with VIRTUAL KEYBOARD only .
i am getting only characters values. like "Pressed:A"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
    et.addTextChangedListener(this);


}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Pressed : " +s.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after)
{

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your afterTextChanged(Editable s) to:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
    String str = s.toString();
    if(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()).equals(" "))
            Toast.makeText(this,"Pressed : Space",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else if(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()).equals("\n"))
        Toast.makeText(this,"Pressed : Enter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
            Toast.makeText(this,"Pressed : " +str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and it will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for post Abhy .Your post is working for me.but on TAB press it is not responding , on CLEAR / DEL press showing "Pressed : Space ".Can you short out this problem.thanks in advance